# VMWare adding interfaces without reboot

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, esxi

I am using VMWare Workstation in my lab and have ESXi host as VMs. When I add a new interface in the VM settings the changes are not propagated in the ESXi host, I have to reboot it every time. If we are using Linux or Windows we can restart the network service, but for ESXi host I don't know what network service should be restarted. I know the DCUI option of restarting the management network, but that is not for the network interfaces itself.
I am using VM, the method of adding new interfaces to the physical ESXi host also would be the same, like to add the interface without the reboot the host that should detect the new or removed interfaces.

Some of these esxcli commands I tried, but no help.

`[root@ESXi1:~] esxcli network nic down -n vmnic1`

`[root@ESXi1:~] esxcli network nic list`

`[root@ESXi1:~] esxcli network nic up -n vmnic1`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The keyword here could be “hotplug“ or “hot plug”, because that’s the operation as seen from inside the VM. Dunno about ESXi specifically though.

Answer (score 0):

The networking stack needs to be updated to reflect changes made when adding or removing a network interface from a virtual machine in ESXi, which might necessitate a host reboot. Refreshing the networking stack, restarting the management network, or restarting the `hostd` service are a few actions that can be taken to try to avoid a reboot. A host reboot might be required if the steps above are unsuccessful.

```
esxcli network refresh
```

```
esxcli network ip interface set -e false -i vmk0
esxcli network ip interface set -e true -i vmk0
```

```
/etc/init.d/hostd restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciate it. I couldn't find the command "esxcli network refresh" and this doesn't exists. Also "esxcli network ip interface set -e false -i vmk0" this is for the VM kernel NIC, but the actual physical NIC is named as vmnic0.